# htaccess rewrite rule to redirect all but one IP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to carry out maintenance on the site and be the only one who can access it. I wrote the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^46\.233\.116\.53
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maydomain.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

I should redirect any IP to the maintenance page except mine (46.233.116.53) but unfortunately is redirecting mine too. I also tried to wrap the rule within

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
.....
</IfModule>
```

But still no luck. Is there anything my hosting should do as they seem to have no suggestion :(

Comment: Your code looks fine. it looks like you didnt copy the correct ip

Answer (score 1):

This is what I currently use.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.000\.00\.00 #Replace with real ip
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.htmlp$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried yours but I get an error message:                          ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS